# Xcode is displaying colors inline in the code

Tags: swift, xcode

How to prevent Xcode from displaying colors inline

```
let colors:[UIColor] = [
    #colorLiteral(red: 0.1019607857, green: 0.2784313858, blue: 0.400000006, alpha: 1),
    #colorLiteral(red: 0.1019607857, green: 0.2784313858, blue: 0.400000006, alpha: 1),
    #colorLiteral(red: 0.1019607857, green: 0.2784313858, blue: 0.400000006, alpha: 1),
    #colorLiteral(red: 0.1019607857, green: 0.2784313858, blue: 0.400000006, alpha: 1),
    #colorLiteral(red: 0.1019607857, green: 0.2784313858, blue: 0.400000006, alpha: 1)
]
```

renders the color values in boxes inline.

How to prevent this from happening?

Comment: I kinda doubt Xcode is writing code for itself :)

Answer (score 1):

The other answers may prevent the color display, but make your code run slower, because every time the initialiser is used there is real code being run to create an Objective-C object. The #colorLiteral doesn't generate *any* code.

And I can't quite get why you are opposed to actually seeing the colors.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `UIColor(red:green:blue:alpha)` initializer instead of color literals.

```
let color = UIColor(red: 0, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like below example:

```
static let Blue : UIColor = UIColor(red: 43.0/255.0, green: 81.0/255.0, blue: 162.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```